# How to arrange the layout when Soft Keyboard opens up in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have searched for various answers for this particular problem but could not find one. I am developing an android application and I am currently up to arranging the layouts.

My problem is when a soft keyboard opens up in a form containing lots of input fields, the buttons at the bottom also keeps coming up. What I want is the buttons should not come up and along with this the form should be scrollable to bottom of the layout while the soft keyboard is still visible.

Before I was trying lots of modes combinations for windowSoftInputMode inside AndroidManifest.xml in the respective activity, but could not get any satisfactory result.

Screenshots:
[The normal form (shown the bottom part) looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF2Q4.png)

[When the soft keyboard opens up, it cuts the lower portion i.e. I am unable to scroll the layout further.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPzZB.png)

I somehow managed to remove the buttons using following code, I do not know whether this is correct or not:

```
<activity
        android:name=".usermanagement.SignUp"
        android:label="साइन अप"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
```

Now I am wondering whether I can scroll to the bottom of the layout while keeping the soft keyboard active and not showing the buttons(Home button and Next button)

Comment: You should be put clear information about you issue.. like Screenshots how you want that..and what is the issue

Comment: Is your `ScrollView`height set to `wrap_content` ?

Comment: It is set to match_parent. @Ricardo

Comment: I have attached the screenshots and elaboration @NehaK